# Gradle exclude all tests for a dependency

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In my Gradle project, I have a dependency, when I run 'gradle test' or 'gradle clean build', it will run the tests for that dependency.

Is there anyway to exclude running ALL tests for that specific dependency only?

Here is a snippet of my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(path:':platform',transitive:false)
  // I want to exclude running ALL tests contained in platform
}
test {
  beforeTest { descriptor ->
    logger.lifecycle("Running test: ${descriptor}")
  }
}
```

Comment: try gradle test -x :platform:test

Comment: @SantoshGokak thanks, but can I make the changes in the builds.gradle instead of passing it during the test command or build.  I am asking because I cannot control the build command.

Comment: Could you please provide a runnable example? I've set up a similar project and on `a` test invocation `b` tests are skipped.